# marking a post that was sticky on category template

Tags: posts, conditional-tags, sticky-post

i want some how to mark the post that has been featured (was a sticky post) in the category template. in wordpress logic it should be something like -

```
was_sticky();
```

anybody?

Comment: I think you could hook on 'save_post' in the admin, to update a meta key ; and then run a query to call all posts that have that meta key.

Comment: @Simon, this is a possibility but i'm trying to avoid a lot of custom coding here... if i won't have any other choice maybe I'll go that road eventually...

Comment: Well, there's nothing built-in to do what you want. A post is sticky or not - no memory of if used to be. That means custom code ^^ - or keep every post sticky forever, and just display the last X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check if »sticky«

There's the [`is_sticky()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_sticky)-[Conditional Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), which you can read about in core [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/post.php#L1589).

### How-to mark as »sticky«

This works for posts, that have the "stick to the front page" check box checked:

[image]

### How »sticky« works internally

So basically the function checks if the post-ID is inside `get_option( 'sticky_posts' );`. That means that you *can't* question if a post *was* "sticky". You can only check which posts *are currently* "sticky".

### Style as many »sticky« posts as you need & style »sticky« them specially

So your only chance would be to show only the number of sticky posts that you need <sup>1)</sup> on the front page and skip the rest. Then you can apply to all your archive posts the [`post_class();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) (inside the loop). This adds different classes to the post, but also the `.sticky` class for "sticky" posts. Which means, that you now have a way to style them differently.

```
.sticky {
    color: #FF00FF;
    background-color: #009ee0;
}
```

<sup>1) You can get the newest sticky posts with `$newest_stickies = array_slice( rsort( get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ), 0, 2 );` - change the last number to the number of posts you need. To add them to the loop, use `'post__in' => $newest_stickies` as argument for your main/front-page query.</sup>

Comment: the issue is what will happened when i will un-check the post as sticky? what i need is a way to know that the post was sticky in the past, when now it isn't... what do you say?

Comment: There's no chance to keep this data. When you uncheck the check box, then you loose the post-ID from the array in the options table entry. So the only chance is to let them stay checked as sticky and only show those that you want where you want (home/front page). In the archive pages, you can then access them as described above. That's the way it's meant to be from core side.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you're right, but I'll let this question hang a little bit before I'm deciding that this is it. thanks.

Comment: The only other option is to intercept the post on update, move it to another option and then question on every loop run if the post ID is inside the new option and then add another class. I'd personally go with the future-proof, default core-solution instead of hacking lots of lines of code into a plugin for a task that's already done. Sidenote: You don't get rep points back if you don't nominate an answer as solution. :)

Comment: Just re-read my comment. You don't get any rep points back at any way. You don't have to mark my (or any other) answer as solution.

Comment: i know. but I want to. cause you spent your time to help me with a solution.